# Scala 2.11 + Neo4j - parboiled dependency of Cypher compiler

Tags: scala, neo4j, sbt

I wanted to upgrade my `Scala` project to `2.11.1` version of the language.

When I updated my `build.sbt` file and tried to compile project I got

```
[error] Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in {file:somePathTo}SomeProject:
[error]    org.parboiled:parboiled-scala _2.11, _2.10
java.lang.RuntimeException: Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.parboiled:parboiled-scala
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at sbt.ConflictWarning$.processCrossVersioned(ConflictWarning.scala:47)
    at sbt.ConflictWarning$.apply(ConflictWarning.scala:30)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$60.apply(Defaults.scala:1090)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$60.apply(Defaults.scala:1090)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
[error] (*:update) Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.parboiled:parboiled-scala
```

at first I was thinking that it is because of my dependency on `Spray` library which also depends on `parboiled` so I posted a question on their user list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spray-user/XY7ceh7a9t0 and they suggested I try view dependency graph for my project.

It seems that parboiled is used not only by `Spray` library but also by Cypher compiler (which I am depending because of my dependence on `Spraing Data Neo4j`).

Both `2.0` and `2.1` versions are using `parboiled` for scala `2.10`.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0/2.0.3
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1/2.1.2

I am wondering if it would be possible/considered safe to remove transitive dependency on this version of `parboiled` library (http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html#exclude-transitive-dependencies) and just add `2.11` to my classpath.

Also I would be grateful if someone from `Neo4j` team could tell if there are any plans to release a version of Cypher compiler that is compiled against `parboiled` for Scala `2.11`.

Just for the completeness here is dependency part of my `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % AkkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % AkkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % AkkaVersion % "test",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence-experimental" % AkkaVersion,
  "io.spray" %% "spray-can" % SprayVersion,
  "io.spray" %% "spray-routing" % SprayVersion,
  "io.spray" %% "spray-testkit" % SprayVersion % "test",
  "io.spray" %% "spray-json" % SprayJsonVersion,
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % LogbackVersion,
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % Specs2Version,
  "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-neo4j" % SDNVersion,
  "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-neo4j-rest" % SDNVersion,
  "javax.validation" % "validation-api" % ValidationAPIVersion,
  "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % NscalaTimeVersion,
  "org.neo4j" % "neo4j-kernel" % Neo4jVersion % "test" classifier "tests",
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % MockitoVersion,
  "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % ScalaLoggingVersion,
  "io.kamon" %% "kamon-core" % KamonVersion,
  "io.kamon" %% "kamon-spray" % KamonVersion,
  "io.kamon" %% "kamon-statsd" % KamonVersion,
  "org.aspectj" % "aspectjweaver" % AspectjVersion
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are definitely plans to update to more recent versions of Scala and also update dependencies such as parboiled. However, Neo4j, being a complex database system, has a large number of dependencies and any change of this nature requires significant effort in migration and testing. Thus, at this time, there is no ETA available for such a change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, at least I know that it is not currently in plans :)

Comment: It is in the plans. Just not sure when it'll appear! :)

Comment: Some. With the move to Java 8, this becomes more important. I'd hope to see something happening with Java 8 and Scala 2.11 during the summer.

Comment: One year  later, still no scala 2.11 support. Moreover, its no documented anywhere, so all people using embedded mode need to discover it themselves through sweat, blood and tears. Did Neo4j become a slow behemoth ;), not running up to speed with the latest and greatest (em ... scala 2.11 is more than two years already) ?

Answer (score 2):

Neo4j 2.3 supports scala 2.11, you can have a sneak peak by downloading and using the [latest milestone of 2.3](http://neo4j.com/blog/new-on-neo4j-the-neo4j-2-3-0-milestone-2-release-is-here).